# How to express every 1.5 days?

Tags: word-request

Ok, we got

everyday: day 1 (on), day 2 (on), day 3 (on), day 4 (on), day 5 (on), etc

Ex: *we eat soup everyday*

every other day / every second day:  day 1 (on), day 2 (off), day 3 (on), day 4 (off), day 5 (on), etc

Ex: *we eat soup every other day*

Ok, now I want it as followings:

0-12h of day 1 (on), 13-24h of day 1 (off), 0-12h of day 2 (off), 13-24h of day 2 (on), day 3 (off), 0-12h of day 4 (on), 13-24h of day 4 (off), etc.

**How to express every 1.5 days**?

Comment: You just said it: *every one and a half days*; alternatively, *every day and a half*. ... Note by the way that *everyday* is an adjective; in your context you must use *every day*.

Comment: Another possible way to say it: *every 36 hours*.

Comment: Every "day and a half" would be a common way to express it.

Answer (score 3):

"Every day-and-a-half", or "every one and a half days", or "every 36 hours".

In some cases "every one-point-five days" is also acceptable.

Answer (score 3):

It's dependent on context.

In casual conversation, one might say "a day and a half" or "one and a half days". However, in a scientific paper for instance, "1.5 days" or "36 hours" may be used instead.